# What is better: many tables or many colums?

Tags: mysql

In my website example , i have 20 different products that anyone can sell and i
 don't know what is better:
1.My table in database has id, name and 20 columns for every product.
2.One table for every product where the user who selling it will be stored there.

Or something else?

Comment: NEITHER!!!!!!!!! Please take a basic SQL tutorial on how to design your DB.

Comment: can you describe those columns?

Comment: Actually, see normalization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Do not do EITHER!!!!!!!!!

You need to read up on relations in databases.

If I get it right from the little info you provide you are looking for a *n to m relation*. This is the general approach:

```
users table
-----------
id   |   name
1    |   peter
2    |   tom


products table
--------------
id   |   name
1    |   washing machine
2    |   hair dryer
3    |   blender


user_products table
-------------------
user_id  |  product_id
1        |  2
2        |  1
2        |  3
```

Answer (score 0):

For a product catalogue, think that a 'table' is for common nouns and a 'row' is for proper nouns. So it makes sense to have a table named 'cars' instead of having tables named 'Dodge_Viper', 'Ferrari' etc...